# Uniform sample space confusions.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose I have a box containing 3 red balls, 5 yellow ones, 2 green ones and 1 white. Suppose I take 5 balls out of the box with no putting back. Being asked about probabilities of events of specified colors of balls I took out, how should I build a uniform sample space? In some solution, I saw that $|\Omega|={11\choose 5}$. Isn't it required that I number all the balls and treat them as different objects? I would appreciate any clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample space of $\binom{11}{5}$ elements is the best one here, if we don't care about the order in which the balls are picked. It does treat the $11$ balls as distinct objects. Note that all $11$ members of  $\Omega$  are equally likely.